# Como ajustar a largura e altura?

Tags: html, edição-de-imagens

Comecei a estudar a html agora, ainda não entrei na parte de css.
No vídeo aula falam que, por exemplo, a largura de uma imagem para colocar em um conteúdo
de um site pode ser 600 ou 650.Eles usam 650 e a altura é automaticamente ajustada, por causa de um recurso do editor. Tentei colocar a largura 650 em uma imagem para testar, a
altura da minha imagem foi automaticamente ajustada pelo editor também. Porém a altura da minha imagem ficou maior, deve ser por a minha imagem original ser maior que a imagem do vídeo aula. Como deveria proceder para deixar a imagem menor, levando em consideração a largura 650?

Comment: _"Comecei a estudar a html agora, ainda não entrei na parte de css."_... HTML e CSS andam juntos. Aprenda os dois.

Answer (score -2):

Não sei se entendi bem, mas você pode tentar trocar a largura em pixels por "auto". Ou então usar object-fit do CSS, que ajusta a imagem dentro de um container

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).